# Font weights in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure and I want to make the axes labels bold. The problem is that the text contains mathematical expressions that do not turn into bold font face. Other parts are Ok.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
predicts = np.random.random(1000)*10e9
plt.plot(predicts,predicts, ".", ms=6)
plt.xlabel("Actual NPV (\$) x$10^9$", fontsize=8, fontweight="bold")
plt.ylabel("Predicted NPV (\$) x$10^9$", fontsize=8, fontweight="bold")
# plt.rcParams["font.weight"] = "regular"
plt.yticks(np.arange(9.4, 10.2, 0.2))
R2 = np.round(r2_score(predicts, predicts),2)
plt.text(x=9.4, y=10, s=f"$R^2$={R2}")
plt.rcParams["font.size"] = 8
fig.tight_layout()
```

The output is shown in the attached image.
[image]

How can I make 10 to the power of 9 bold, too?

I have tried fontweight in axis labels, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\mathbf{}` in you inline math, e.g.,

```
plt.xlabel("Actual NPV (\$) x$\mathbf{10^9}$", fontsize=8, fontweight="bold")
```